# How create a pandas dataframe for encoding nltk frequency-distributions

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

Hej, I´m an absolute beginner in Python (a linguist by training) and don´t know how to put the twitter-data, which I scraped with Twint (stored in a `csv-file`), into a `DataFrame` in Pandas to be able to encode `nltk frequency-distributions`.
Actually I´m even not sure if it is important to create a test-file and a train-file, as I did (see code below). I know it´s a very basic question. However, to get some help would be great! Thank you.

This is what I have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("test_newtest90.csv") 
data = pd.read_csv("train_newtest90.csv")

import re
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np 
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import seaborn as sns
import string
import nltk
import warnings 
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore", category=DeprecationWarning)

%matplotlib inline

train  = pd.read_csv("train_newtest90.csv")
test = pd.read_csv("test_newtest90.csv")
combi = train.append(test, ignore_index=True)
```

If I check:

```
combi["tidy_tweet"].dtypes
```

I get this:

```
dtype("0")
```

Comment: Hi there, welcome to Stack Overflow! Am I right in understanding that you are trying to establish a word frequency distribution for the combined tweets in your dataframe?

Comment: @RJAdriaansen: Hej, thanks! You´re right. I need a dataframe to be able to evaluate frequency distribution, concordance, make visualizations like wordclouds etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to split your csv in a train and a test set. That's only needed if you are going to train a model, which is not the case. So simply load the original unsplit csv file:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
```

The next step is to clean the tweets to get rid of hashtags, urls, etc:

```
import regex as re

# use RegEx to clean tweets
def cleaningTweets(twt):
    twt = re.sub('@[A-Za-z0-9]+', '', twt)
    twt = re.sub('#', '', twt)
    twt = re.sub('https?:\/\/\S+', '', twt)
    return twt

# apply previous function to the current df, assuming the relevant column name is "tweets"
df.tweets = df.tweets.apply(cleaningTweets)
# make all words lowercase
df.tweets = df.tweets.str.lower()
```

Now you can start doing fun stuff like word frequency counts. But in order to so it is advised to first remove stop words and punctuation marks:

```
import nltk
import string 

# load a list of stopwords from nltk to clean the tweets from stop words
nltk.download('stopwords')
stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english')
#remove stopwords and punctuation
df['no_stopwords'] = df.tweets.apply(lambda x: ' '.join([i for i in x.split(" ") if i not in string.punctuation if i not in stopwords]))
# count word frequency
df_word_freq = df.no_stopwords.str.split(expand=True).stack().value_counts()
# save the top 50 to csv
df_word_freq.head(50).to_csv('word_count.csv')
#df_word_freq.to_csv('word_count.csv') for saving the entire df
# create bar chart of top 50
df_word_freq.head(50).plot.bar()
```

Or you could make a word cloud:

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud

# first merge all tweets into one string
whole_words = " ".join([tweets for tweets in df.tweets])
# feed the string to WordCloud
word_cloud = WordCloud(width = 700, height = 500, random_state = 1, min_font_size = 10, stopwords = stopwords).generate(whole_words)
# save wordcloud as png file
word_cloud.to_file('wordcloud.png')
```

I hope this gets you started!

Comment: Great, it works fine! Thank you! I would have two additional questions: Is there a way to show the whole word-frequency-list or say the 50 most frequent words and save it in a csv-file to have access? And how can I accomplish to visualize the most frequent words in a plot?

Comment: I have updated the answer addressing your questions. Pandas has very elaborate [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/index.html) where you can find more information, for example about various possibilities to [visualize](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/visualization.html) your data.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definetly check out the pandas docs. I´m just getting started with NLP and Python as a linguist and can´t get enough of it, just have to structure my overall approach so your tipps come in very handy! Maybe I should take an online NLP-Course?! Thanks for dealing with my questions, which are, I know, yet very basic!

Comment: Great, it can be very rewarding! I'm a historian myself and can confirm that programming will definitely enlarge your toolkit. Learning by doing works fine is my experience, and there are plenty of tutorials and courses available to get started. good luck!